# winapi - Should I override CButton or CWnd to create a custom control?

Tags: c++, windows

I understand that CButton, CEdit, etc are all conveniant classes that are easy to implement, but to overriding them and stop certain super class functions to implement your own button functionallity, is a bit of a hastle. Wouldn't it be more practical just to override CWnd and start from scratch? This is more a principal-based question, ie is it bad practice to start from scratch like that? In my view it makes more sense, but I don't want to have what is considered badly-writen code..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to get all the nuances of a standard control, so if yours will be expected to fill the same role you should probably start from the standard.

Also the standard controls can be placed in a dialog and overridden later. A plain CWnd will need to be created explicitly.

On the other hand, overriding the way Microsoft designed a control to work can be maddening sometimes.

Unfortunately it's a judgement call in the end. Every case will be different and it's impossible to make a blanket recommendation.

Comment: Yeah looking at it now its more of a case of what you are doing in the perticular instance. I was just a bit sceptical towards overriding MFC classes because my experiences with creating a custom frame via overriding CWndFrame was very 'maddening'. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but if your custom control is, say, a button, then it will simply be much easier to inherit CButton.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is always better to start from classes like CButton to enhance a button, CEdit to enhance an edit control. This way you don't have to re-write the control's basic functionality & control notification messages.

As far as UI is concerned, you have equal control over overriding the UI in CButton compared to CWnd. So it is better to enhance CButton.

Moreover, remember CButton can be radio button, checkbox etc. Getting all that with plain CWnd would mean lot of work.